# Where the heck do I get `tzfile.h`?

Tags: timezone

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to compile a program that requires a header called `tzfile.h`. Problem is I can't find a Ubuntu package for it and the place it tells me to download the "tzcode" package from, `ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/`, *is dead*. Where do I get this file from? I want to be able to properly install it, too. Not just download it to my downloads folder.

Answer (score 3):

See:

http://www.iana.org/time-zones

This is part of the `tzcode` package.